# What are some exceptional movies / documentaries on macroeconomics?

Tags: macroeconomics

I would like to know a few movies / documentaries that are based on macroeconomics

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about economic science.

Comment: How is it different from a book recommendation?

Comment: The Commanding Heights: The Battle for the World Economy / 'traces the rise of free markets during the last century, as well as the process of globalization and presents a condemnation of the corruption and failure of centrally planned economies' ?

Comment: @VicAche what Lasse said

Comment: @Lasse very. A book *on/about* economics can be (marginally, IMO) on topic, a book "*based on*" macroeconomics is not.

Answer (score 2):

Princes of the Yen is a documentary that springs to mind.

Answer (score 1):

[Nova's Trillion Dollar Bet](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/stockmarket/) episode (documentary)

[The Big Short](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1596363/) (fictionalized movie about true events)

[Grapes of Wrath](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032551/) might be considered a fictional story about the macroeconomics of the great depression.

[Wall Street](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094291/) might be considered a fictional story about the economic dislocations of the reforms of the US economy in the 1970s and 1980s and how these reforms raised productivity while increasing inequality and supporting a popular perception of amoral finance.

Answer (score 1):

[Inequality for All (2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2215151/) is a good movie, although it is focused more on labor economics.